# Transcription please. What is she saying?

Tags: spoken-english

When I was watching [**this ABC news,**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-n6DbrY5ek)

I could not catch what the female doctor is saying from 1:25～

"For every illegal price *******************".

Could someone help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a transcription service.

Comment: Okay, I know the rule, please proceed. However, as Johnny is saying at his answer, her pronunciation is quite mixed and dialectic, so for non native speakers, especially like me who are unfamiliar with non U.S pronunciation, it is very hard to understand. Hope you understand me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speaker has a mixed British regional and Australian accent, and speaks quickly, so I'm not surprised you had trouble understanding. From 1:26:

> For every illegal operation that happens, there's a donor somewhere suffering, and he won't be bought out of poverty, and he won't get appropriate medical care.

The *he* in those clauses is the donor who is operated on illegally to remove their organ.

Comment: Donor sounds like a "dinner" to me and the "appropriate" sounds very dialectic. I appreciate your help.